# Coding (automation) with selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2

I need help!

I have thoroughly studied **selenium IDE** and now I want to proceed with **coding using selenium(scripting)**, how and where should I start.

I have setup complete environment settings with eclipse but do not have an idea how I should start scripting.

I don't have any projects officially allotted for the same, I want to do it on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you set selenium properly.

1 - Go to your eclipse.

2 - Go to menu **File ->New -> Java project**. Give project name like "test" or anything you like.

3 - Click on **Next**.

4 - Select tab **"Libraries"** , Select option **"Add external JARs"**

5 - Add following 3 JARs :

```
  A- selenium-java-2.43.1
  B- selenium-java-2.43.1-srcs
  C- selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0
```

6 - click on **Finish**. [Your project creation steps completed here]

7 - Now , Do right click on your project folder and select new->class

8 - Give class name and tick option "public static void main(String[] args]"and click on finish.

Please add below code before your classname in code :

```
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
```

After above step , run following sample selenium web driver code to open site :

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Hope above will help you better.

Other selenium helpful tutorial : [Selenium Tutorial](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/selenium-introduction/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @HelpingHands  this was really helpful, but what I really wanted to know is what should i start with, like script for opening mail or counting no of broken links etc or something else what would be easier to start with.  As we start with a hello world program while learning some language

Comment: The link provide is really gud

Comment: First you should learn all methods of selenium then you can start to use one by one in program. Methods are important. Once you use my shared tutorial , you will see learning sequence.